# How to use Cygwin from MATLAB to execute commands in other directories?

Tags: windows, matlab, cygwin

I am using **MATLAB** and I want to execute some **C++** programs using **CYGWIN** under Windows. These are within a local directory of CYGWIN; `C:\cygwin\home\Alex\Community_BGLL_CPP`. I can get CYGWIN to perform commands under the local directory of MATLAB:

```
>> ls
.                README           genlouvainmex.m  
..               genlouvain.m     private          
>> system('C:\cygwin\bin\ls')
README
genlouvain.m
genlouvainmex.m
private
ans =
 0
```

But I cannot get the command executed as if within CYGWIN's local directory. This is so I can start a C++ program to produce a text file that I can then use MATLAB to process. So in essence I just need to call it. Here I experiment with `ls`:

```
>> system('C:\cygwin\bin\ C:\cygwin\home\Alex\ls')
'C:\cygwin\bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
ans =
 1
```

I also tried `>> system('C:\cygwin\bin\ls C:\cygwin\home\Alex\')` but it also does not work.

one option is to change directory (`cd`) into the CYGWIN one and then perform the command:

```
>> pwd
ans =
c:\cygwin\home\Alex\Community_BGLL_CPP\sample_networks
>> system('C:\cygwin\bin\ls')
arxiv.bin
arxiv.txt
example.bin
example.txt
graph.tree
graph_list.bin
graph_list.txt
karate.bin
karate.tree
karate.txt
ans =
 0
```

Comment: Indeed `C:\cygwin\bin\ ` is not an executable. You could try something like `system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c C:\cygwin\home\Alex\ls')` to call your C++ program (ls here) from a Cygwin-shell.

Comment: @Tobold, I ran the command but it produced an error `>> system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c C:\cygwin\home\Alex\ls')
/usr/bin/bash: C:cygwinhomeAlexls: command not found, ans=127` why do you think it removes the slashes to make *C:cygwinhomeAlexls*?

Comment: Hm, I am not sure and cannot test it right now. Maybe you need to escape the backslashes (like `\\ ` ). Or try to put quotation marks like this `system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "C:\cygwin\home\Alex\ls"')`. My guess is escaping is what's needed.

Comment: @Tobold, the escape backslashes work `>> system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c C:\\cygwin\\home\\Alex\\ls')
/usr/bin/bash: C:\cygwin\home\Alex\ls: command not found` but the command is still not executed. I am stuck on what to do

Comment: You could try the `-l` flag for cygwin. `system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -c -l "C:\\cygwin\\home\\Alex\\ls"')`

Comment: @Tobold, thanks, but still no joy

Comment: @Tobold, would it be possible to *open* cygwin from matlab and *feed* it stdin as if it was typed?

Comment: Just to make sure: there is an executable called `ls` in `C:\cygwin\home\Alex\ `? Or do you want to execute `ls` in the folder `C:\cygwin\home\Alex\ `? If this were the case you can do `system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l -c "ls C:\\cygwin\\home\\Alex\\"')` or `system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l -c "cd C:\\cygwin\\home\\Alex\\; ls"')` BTW: in my previous comment the order of `-l` and `-c` was wrong.

Comment: @Tobold, I would like to execute a program called `convert` but I thought that being able to do something like `ls` is a first step. And what is weird is that `ls` works but it always produces results from the same directory `>> system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l -c ls C:\\cygwin\\home\\Alex\\Community_BGLL_CPP')
Community_BGLL_CPP
Community_latest
>> system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l -c ls C:\\cygwin\\home\\') Community_BGLL_CPP Community_latest`
The same directory listing comes out regardless of the input provided

Comment: So there is no executable called ls in the folder. I think you are missing quotation marks around the command (after the c flag) such that only ls is executed and the following path is ignored. Just a guess, again. But it actually doesn't matter since you want to execute convert anyway.

Comment: @Tobold, `system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l -c "ls C:\\cygwin\\home\\"')
ls: cannot access C:cygwinhome: No such file or directory` and I also try to execute the program as well `system('C:\cygwin\bin\bash -l -c C:\\cygwin\\home\\Community_BGLL_CPP\\convert -i sample_networks\\karate.txt -o sample_networks\\karate.bin')
-i: C:\cygwin\home\Community_BGLL_CPP\convert: command not found`

Comment: Looks like the backslash doesn't work as a path separator, you might try a slash instead. You could also test whether execution works when done manually from a Cygwin shell.

Comment: @Tobold, from the cygwin shell it all works fine manually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have cygwin installed, so I can't test this for sure.
But I think you just need a 'cd' as part of your system command.
E.g.:

```
>> system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\bash" -c "cd  C:/Python27; C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Git/bin/ls"')
```

produces a listing of my Python folder, because ls is run in that folder.

So you want something like:

```
>> system('"C:\cygwin\bin\bash" -c "cd  C:/cygwin/home/Alex/Community_BGLL_CPP/sample_networks; C:/some_path/convert"')
```